# Nginx Docker 400 Bad Request

Tags: nginx, docker, nexus, http-status-code-400, bad-request

I am currently trying to host nexus as a private registry for docker images within my organisation . My nginx configuration are as below .

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {

            listen 6666;   ### Docker Hosted Repo HTTPS port
            server_name box.company.net;  ### Nexus Server
            keepalive_timeout 60;

            ssl on;
            ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nexus.crt;
            ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/nexus.key;
            ssl_ciphers HIGH:!kEDH:!ADH:!MD5:@STRENGTH;
            ssl_session_cache shared:TLSSSL:16m;
            ssl_session_timeout 10m;
            ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

            client_max_body_size 0;
            chunked_transfer_encoding on;

            location /v2/ {


                    if ($http_user_agent ~ "^(docker\/1\.(3|4|5(?!\.[0-9]-dev))|Go ).*$" ) {
                    return 404;
                    }
                    error_log               /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
                    access_log              /var/log/nginx/docker.log;
                    proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
                    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto "https";
                    proxy_pass             http://box.company.net:4444/;
                    proxy_read_timeout      900;
        }

            location / {

                    error_log               /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
                    access_log              /var/log/nginx/docker.log;
                    proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
                    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto "https";
                    proxy_pass              http://box.company.net:4444/;
                    proxy_read_timeout      90;
        }
    }
```

Have configured an hosted docker repo within nexus(running on port 4444) with https port 6666.

Currently we are able to login to docker registry .

> [test@server ~]$ docker login -u admin -p admin123
>   box.company.net:6666 Login Succeeded

But when we try to push tagged images to the nexus hosted docker registry it throws back 400 Bad Request error .

> [test@server ~]$ docker push box.company.net:6666/alpine
>   The push refers to a repository [box.company.net:6666/alpine]
>   3fb66f713c9f: Preparing error parsing HTTP 400 response body: invalid
>   character '<' looking for beginning of value: "\n\n\n\n  400 - Nexus Repository
>   Manager\n  \n\n\n  \n 
>   (new
>   Image).src=\"https://box.company.net:6666/favicon.ico?3.2.1-01\"</script>\n
>   \n  https://box.company.net:6666/favicon-32x32.png?3.2.1-01\"
>   sizes=\"32x32\">\n  https://box.company.net:6666/safari-pinned-tab.svg?3.2.1-01\" color=\"#5bbad5\">\n  https://box.company.net:6666/favicon-16x16.png?3.2.1-01\"
>   sizes=\"16x16\">\n  https://box.company.net:6666/favicon.ico?3.2.1-01\">\n 
>   https://box.company.net:6666/mstile-144x144.png?3.2.1-01\">\n  \n\n  https://box.company.net:6666/static/css/nexus-content.css?3.2.1-01\"/>\n\n\n\n  https://box.company.net:6666\">\n    \n      https://box.company.net:6666/static/images/nexus.png?3.2.1-01\"/>\n
>   \n    \n      \n        Nexus Repository Manager\n      \n
>   \n        OSS 3.2.1-01\n      \n    \n
>   \n\n\n\n  \n    https://box.company.net:6666/static/rapture/resources/icons/x32/exclamation.png?3.2.1-01\"/>\n
>   Error 400\n    Bad Request\n  \n  \n    \n
>   HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL\n    \n
>   \n\n\n\n\n"

Am I missing some important nginx configuration? Or are my requests getting malformed.

Comment: Maybe https://serverfault.com is a better place to ask such question.

Comment: By the way: At the end of your error message you can find " Error 400\n Bad Request\n \n \n \n HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL". Maybe this will lead you into the right direction.

Comment: But it's not specifying what url it's forming to post the images

Comment: Then have a look at my first comment.

Comment: @reporter ok..I will post my question on the suggested link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its working now . Below are my nginx configuration.

```
server {

    proxy_send_timeout 120;
    proxy_read_timeout 300;
    proxy_buffering    off;
    tcp_nodelay        on;

    server_tokens off;
    client_max_body_size 1G;

    listen 80;
    server_name box.company.net;
    location / {
          rewrite ^(.*) https://box.company.net$1 permanent;
    }
}

server {

    listen 443;
    server_name box.company.net;
    keepalive_timeout 60;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nexus.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/nexus.key;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!kEDH:!ADH:!MD5:@STRENGTH;
    ssl_session_cache shared:TLSSSL:16m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location / {

      proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto "https";
      proxy_pass              http://box.company.net:8082;
      proxy_read_timeout      90;

    }
}

# correlates to your nexus http connector
server {

    listen 6666;
    server_name box.company.net;
    keepalive_timeout 60;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nexus.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/nexus.key;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!kEDH:!ADH:!MD5:@STRENGTH;
    ssl_session_cache shared:TLSSSL:16m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    client_max_body_size 1G;
    chunked_transfer_encoding on;

    ### Block for Search,Pull,Push of Docker Images via Nexus Hosted Repo ####
    location / {

      access_log              /var/log/nginx/docker.log;
      proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        if ($request_method !~* GET) {
                proxy_pass              http://box.company.net:4444;
        }
        if ($request_method = GET) {
                proxy_pass              http://box.company.net:5555;
        }
      proxy_read_timeout      90;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Adding proxy headers solved this issue.
`proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto "https";`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the namespace when pushing your image.

Take a look into the documentation (https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/docker.html#_accessing_repositories):

```
docker <command> <nexus-hostname>:<repository-port>/<namespace>/<image>:<tag>
```

You could try it with

```
docker push server.int.org.com:6666/alpine/alpine
```

Comment: Still the same error.  Are the nginx configurations correct??